# WebSockets don't send when testing with Jasmine

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, websocket, jasmine

I'm trying to run a Jasmine 2.2 test on a WebSocket application that has been written using regular JavaScript, so I have no dependencies. The WebSocket handshake works perfectly fine, but attempts to send messages result in an InvalidStateError. I suspect that this is because the WebSocket hasn't finished opening yet, so I've tried adding a delay to the WebSocket call - but that doesn't work. I've also tried running it asynchronously, but that hasn't worked either.

Here are the relevant current parts of my code.

```
var webSocket;
var url = "ws://localhost:8080/CustomerControllerWeb/chat";

describe("Open a WebSocket", function()
{
beforeAll(function()
{
    jasmine.clock().install();
    webSocket = new WebSocket(url);

});

afterAll( function()
{
    jasmine.clock().uninstall();
});

        it("Should be able to connect", function()
{

webSocket.onopen = function()
{
    console.log("Websocket opened");

};

webSocket.onerror = function(event)
{
    console.log("Error! " + event.data);
};

webSocket.onmessage = function (event)
{
    console.log(event.data);
};

webSocket.onclose = function(event)
{
    console.log("Closed the webSocket");    
};

// expect it to be in state opening (0)
expect(webSocket.readyState).toBe(READY_OPEN);

});


it ("Should be able to send a message", function()
{

    console.log("Trying to send a message!");

    // call a timeout, and then advance the clock.
    setTimeout(sendMessage(message), 1000);
    jasmine.clock().tick(1001);

});
```

I'm quite new to Jasmine, so there's probably something I overlooked here.